# Limit for a sequence with n as an exponent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm having trouble with this problem because it has $n$ as an exponent. Which I'm not really sure on how to deal with.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{4+(-1)^n}{n^2}$$

Comment: Write down the first few terms explicitly: $$\frac39,\quad \frac{5}{16},\quad \frac{3}{25},\quad \frac5{36},\quad \frac3{49},\quad \frac5{64},\quad \frac3{81},\quad \frac5{100},\quad \ldots$$ where does this seem to go?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{3}{n^2} \leq \lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{4+(-1)^n}{n^2} \leq \lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{5}{n^2}$

Which gives:

$0 \leq \lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{4+(-1)^n}{n^2} \leq 0$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $n^2$ is much greater when it tends to infinity than $(-1)^n$; what will be if $(-1)^n$ is divided by $n^2$?

Comment: does this mean the denominator will be much greater than the numerator, resulting in a small number?

Comment: yes and which are the smallest dumbers near 0?

Comment: I would have to assume decimals?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: compute the limits of the subsequences with odd indices, and those with even indices.